# GWT application if event not ready do not show the main login page

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT application in which when another server consider server 1 with a specific task to perform completes its calculation it triggers the main application server called server 2 on which my application is deployed.
I want to implement a method in which when the server 1 times out the server 2 main login page will not be displayed instead a message should be displayed saying "Server still calculating information". On which event should I implement a procedure which will do this ?

Consider a diagrammatic flow representation of the above mentioned procedure.

Server 1-------> calculates -------> completes calculation ----> triggers application server---->displayes login page---->User logs in---> main application is shown.

What I want to implement

If
Server 1 ---> fails ----> triggers application server ----> displays message "Server still calculating information ---> login page not displayed --> application does not load.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume you're using GWT RPC to communicate with your server. In which case my solution would be to simply display the "Server still calculating" message as your default page, and then load in the actual page when the RPC call returns.

Hook your logic into the OnSuccess of your async, and this should do what you need.